# Jboss monitoring of datasource in deployments folder

Tags: java, jboss, datasource

I have to monitor via web console of jboss as 7.1datasources , but when i add them not in standlone.xml but separetely in deployments folder they are not tracked in.management console.
They are only tracked when i add them in standalone.xml

Any idea?

Comment: How exactly did you add a data source in the deployments folder?

Answer (score 0):

When you create datasource-ds.xml like write in jboss [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/apbs03.html) you assign jndi name, for example `MySqlDS`. After that in standalone.xml you have to add this jndi-name in datasource section.

Comment: It is not possible to monitor the datasource created outside standalone.xml file via management console in AS 7.